# C++ map indices to sorted indices

Tags: algorithm, sorting

A standard problem in many languages is to sort an array and sort the indices as well. So for instance, if `a = {4,1,3,2}` the sorted array is `b = {1,2,3,4}` and the original indices moved would be `{1,3,2,0}`. This is easy to do by sorting a vector of pairs for instance.

What I want instead is an array `c` so that `c[i]` is the new position of element `a[i]` in the array `b`. So, in my example, `c = {3,0,2,1}` because `4` moves to position `3`, `1` moved to position `0` and so on.

One way is to look up each element `a[i]` in `b` (perhaps using binary search to reduce lookup time) and then add the corresponding index in `c`. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this problem yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you assume that you have the array of originally indices moved?  It's the only array above that you didn't assign to a variable.  If so, one efficient way of solving this problem is to back calculate it from that array of original indices moved.

You have that as `{1,3,2,0}`.  All you need to do it march through it and put each values index at the value indicated.

So index 0 has a 1.  That means at index 1 of the new array there should be a zero. Index 1 is a 3, so at index 3 of the new array put a 1.  You would get your goal of `{3,0,2,1}`